# Samsung Galaxy G6 System Warning

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, system-error

I have the Samsung Galaxy G6 and keep getting a SYSTEM WARNING
I have added three pictures of the warning I get (all the same warning)
Does anyone know why I keep getting this warning and how do I remove it??

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you going to that web page?  It's pretending to be Google and lying about the error.  Is it set as your home page?  You probably installed an app that changed it or is opening that page itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is such a thing as a "battery virus" (what would they infect?)  sounds like a scam.  What did you recently install?  i would uninstall any new apps and see if this disappear.  I would NOT under any circumstances click on the"OK" button.  It may allow the installation of malware.

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a battery virus and I am always amazed about how many people fall for it.

Comment: @EthanZ I'd bet some even would put their device into the microwave for 10 min if advised such to remove/kill this "bad virus" (or get a "quick charge", pick your choice).

Comment: Unfortunetly so. I have a great response to this but it would be offtopic. Just known that if something sounds dumb and fake, it probably is.